# Why am I getting these errors with filing in Java?

Tags: java

I am filing right now for this big project which I have, it is about to be due in a matter of hours, and my teacher has this textbook on his webpage called Blue Pelican, which I always refer to. My program consists of the user inputting 3 numbers (integers) to get the output from a file.  However, when I followed the textbook through, I got 4 errors which I am unable to solve:

```
if (choose == 1) //enemies from the original Kingdom Hearts
        {
        System.out.println("In the orginal Kingdom Hearts, there is only one enemy race, which is the Heartless.");
        System.out.println("Please type the number which corresponds to the Heartless enemy type.");
        System.out.println("1. Pureblood"); //Gives the display for the user to know she can choose to view Pureblood Heartless.
        System.out.println("2. Emblum"); //Gives the display for the user to know she can choose to view Emblem Heartless.
        System.out.println("3. Special Heartless");
        int heartless_1 = kH.nextInt();
        if (heartless_1 == 1) //gives the chioce to select the Heartless enemy type
        {
            Scanner kH1 = new Scanner(new File("KH_Pureblood_Heartless.txt"));
            int maxIndex = -1; //So that when it's incremented below, the first index is 0.

            String kh1Purebloods = new String[10000]; //To be safe, more than what's needed is declared just in case.

            while (kh1.hasNext())
            {
                maxIndex++;
                kh1Purebloods[maxIndex] = kH1.nextLine();
            }

            kH1.close();

            for (int a = 0; a <= maxIndex; a++)
            {
                System.out.println(kh1Purebloods[a]);
            }
        }
```

The errors I get consist of:

```
E:\3 IB Computer Science SL\Dossier Computer Science IA The Solution\Product\Kingdom_Hearts.java:45: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.String[]
required: java.lang.String
                String kh1Purebloods = new String[10000]; //To be safe, more than what's needed is declared just in case.
                                       ^


E:\3 IB Computer Science SL\Dossier Computer Science IA The Solution\Product\Kingdom_Hearts.java:47: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method hasNext()
location: class kh1
                while (kh1.hasNext())
                          ^


E:\3 IB Computer Science SL\Dossier Computer Science IA The Solution\Product\Kingdom_Hearts.java:50: array required, but java.lang.String found
                    kh1Purebloods[maxIndex] = kH1.nextLine();
                                 ^


E:\3 IB Computer Science SL\Dossier Computer Science IA The Solution\Product\Kingdom_Hearts.java:57: array required, but java.lang.String found
                    System.out.println(kh1Purebloods[a]);
                                                    ^
4 errors

Process completed.
```

And here's the [Blue Pelican Textbook](http://ib-cmptrsci-sl-p2-yrh-m.gar-fieldhs.schools.pwcs.edu/modules/locker/files/get_group_file.phtml?fid=17573251&gid=3518935&sessionid=2562f231721c0920e36c088e09c4df05) I used for reference (Refer 24-3):

Answer (score 3):

`String kh1Purebloods = new String[10000]` kh1Purebloods is a String but you are trying to assign an array to it. Since on line 57 you access it as an array, it should be: `String[] kh1Purebloods = new String[10000]`

You use `kh1` but the scanner is `kH1` (Java is case sensitive)